# How Can You Align a Grid Row to the Top and Bottom and Have the Middle Fill the Rest of the Screen

Tags: maui

I'm trying to build a UI where there's a small section that's always at the top of the page, and a small section that's always at the bottom.  The middle section I want to have fill up the entire rest of the page height.  I thought it would be something like the XAML below but it's not working - the middle section never fills up the available space.  Was hoping someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.  Simplified markup below:

```xml
    <Grid RowDefinitions="60,*,60" ColumnDefinitions="*">

    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <!-- top stuff here -->
    </HorizontalStackLayout>

    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Fill">             
        <!-- middle section here  -->
    </VerticalStackLayout>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
        <!-- bottom section here -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**NOTE:**  When pasting into this question the editor strips out the closing <//Grid> tag.

Comment: I would expect this to work.  Try assigning background colors to each layout so you can visualize them easier.  It may be that the content in the middle section is not large enough to fill its container?  A screenshot would help illustrate the problem.

Comment: Need more info. The markup you show works for me. See questions at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, use `..AndExpand` to be sure all space is used.

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="60,*,60" ColumnDefinitions="*"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    ...
    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ...
```

---

**UPDATE**

Actually, your original code does what it should for me, testing on both Windows and Android, when I set `MainPage = new MainPage();` and have that code in MainPage. With a BackgroundColor on the middle part, so I can see it expand as desired.

So, what is different in your setup?

- Are you using AppShell?
- Testing on platform other than Windows or Android?
- You didn't test the "simplified markup" you show, so the problem is elsewhere in your actual markup?

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggested and realized that it fails when I put the whole Grid block in a ScrollView. So if a ScrollView is the parent, then the Fill part for the VerticalStackLayout in the second Grid row doesn't seem to work. Not sure if that's expected or not, but as I'm thinking about it now I can see how it wouldn't have worked anyways, even if the Fill part worked as I thought it would.

Comment: Yeah, you’d need the scrollview inside that middle row. Otherwise, the layout makes no sense.